# Why import contractions is not working in colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, lstm, text-processing

I'm trying to "import contractions" for my NLP project in google colab but it is not working.

whats the reason for my problem and also solution for it

Answer (score 0):

In a jupyter notebook use:

```
    import sys  
    !{sys.executable} -m pip install contractions

    import contractions
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-expand-contractions-in-text-processing/

Answer (score -1):

```
!pip install contractions
import contractions
```